# ObjectListView editing doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I'm trying to create a simple listbox with ObjectListView (WinForm, C#). The goal is to have a single value (a double) and a check box.

I want to be able to edit the double value by Single Click, so here are the relevant lines of code from my MyWindow.Designer.cs file (i've left out the default values for efficiency):

```
this.olvDepths = new BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView();
this.olvColumn1 = ((BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn)(new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn()));

...

this.olvDepths.CellEditActivation = BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.CellEditActivateMode.SingleClick;
this.olvDepths.CheckBoxes = true;
this.olvDepths.CheckedAspectName = "IsDefault";
this.olvDepths.FullRowSelect = true;

// 
// olvColumn1
// 
this.olvColumn1.AspectName = "Depth";
this.olvColumn1.Text = "";
this.olvColumn1.IsEditable = true;
```

I then create a list of my class (`ShieldingEntry`) and use the `olvDepths.SetObjects()` with the list.  My `ShieldingEntry` class looks like this:

```
public class ShieldingEntry
{
    public double Depth { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I click the field, it doesn't go into edit mode. I've also tried the DoubleClick, SingleClickAlways, and F2Only modes and they don't work either.

The Checkbox works fine.

************** I have additional information *********************

I've pulled and build the ObjectListView source, so I could step through it.

I put a breakpoint in the OLV StartCellEdit method and it gets called and appears to setup and select the control appropriately. It just never appears...

As I noted in the comments on the answer below, I've got this control on a tabbed dialog, and if I switch to another tab, then back, the control works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Interesting. I bet I have used editable OLV on a TabControl before, without problems. Did you create a minimal form with just a TabControl and the OLV to test it or are you still in your target application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ObjectListView before, and here is what I had to do:

Handle the CellEditStarting event. This event is raised when the cell goes into edit mode. Since OLV doesn't really have built-in editors, you have to make your own. Then handle the CellEditFinishing event to validate the data before putting it back into your model.

So first, handling the CellEditStarting event:

```
    private void objlv_CellEditStarting(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Column.AspectName gives the model column name of the editing column

        if (e.Column.AspectName == "DoubleValue")
        {
            NumericUpDown nud = new NumericUpDown();
            nud.MinValue = 0.0;
            nud.MaxValue = 1000.0;
            nud.Value = (double)e.Value;
            e.Control = nud;
        }
    }
```

This creates your editing control. If you want to make sure the size is right, you can set the size of the control (in this case a NumericUpDown) to the cell bounds using e.CellBounds from the event object.

This will show the editor when you click in the cell. Then you can handle the editor finished event to validate the data:

```
    private void objlv_CellEditFinishing(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.AspectName == "DoubleValue")
        {
            //Here you can verify data, if the data is wrong, call
            if ((double)e.NewValue > 10000.0)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

I don't think handling it is required, but its good practice to validate data from the user.

The editing control in the CellEditStarting event can be any control, even a user defined one. I've used a lot of user defined controls (like textboxes with browse buttons) in the cell editor.

[Edit]

I uploaded an example here [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb1pxb7zyoorbsm/ObjectListView.zip?dl=0) that seems to work. Might not be in the exact view as needed, but seems to do the job.

Comment: Not to dispute you, but it does appear that OLV has a FloatCellEditor, which is what e.Control is set to when I get into CellEditStarting. Either way, your response didn't fix my problem.

Comment: What if you try turning the "full row select" off? That may be having an issue activating a single cell if you are trying to select the entire row...

Comment: No difference. It almost appears like it's trying to instantiate the editor, but then the editor loses focus.

Comment: I uploaded a project that shows it working, maybe you can see something that is different with it. The SingleClick wouldn't work but SingleClickAlways did the trick for me.

Comment: objlv.CellEditActivation=ObjectListView.CellEditActivateMode.SingleClick;

Comment: محمد النعيمي  the third line of code in my sample has that.

Comment: I've got this control on a tabbed dialog. If I go to another tab and back, then the editing works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem.  I had it specifically when trying to edit a 'null' value in a decimal? on the OLV on a tab page.  Solution for me was to set UseCustomSelectionColors to 'False'.  I didn't look elsewhere to see if it was reported as a bug.  Seems like a bug.